# Laravel migrate to MySql error: there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, mysql, model, migration, laravel-8

I'm trying to migrate update class User in .php file to MySql table. (i miss a field of users table and want to add this field via User class and re-migrate)
Command i tried: php artisan migrate:fresh.

Below is my code:
_create_users_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->tinyInteger('is_admin',2);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

The field i missed in users table is "is_admin" field (i expected the type of value is integer. I haved try ->integer and ->tinyInteger before but still got the error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`
Hope your help! Thanks so much!

Comment: Remove `2` from `$table->tinyInteger('is_admin');`

Comment: @Siddharth it's work bro, thanks so much. And i have already read description of this method: `public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false) { }`